# How to get the id of an element on a button click in mootools(1.1)

Tags: javascript, mootools, click, element

I have a bunch of links with non-pre-determined id's like so:

```
<a href="#" class="remove_pid" id="pid_123">Remove 123</a>
<a href="#" class="remove_pid" id="pid_234">Remove 234</a>
<a href="#" class="remove_pid" id="pid_567">Remove 567</a>
<a href="#" class="remove_pid" id="pid_890">Remove 890</a>
```

I have an event handler like so:

```
$$('.remove_pid').addEvents({
   'click': removePid
});
```

which calls this function

```
function removePid(event)
{
    alert('yo what is my element id???');
}
```

So the question is how do i get the element id in the function removePid()?

**UPDATE:**

@Aishwar, event.target.id seems to work in the following case, but not specifically in my case

```
<a href="#" class="remove_pid"><img src="/123.jpg" id="pid_123"></a>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I thought it was inconsequential, but instead of the text "Remove 123" I actually have an image like so:

```
<a href="#" class="remove_pid" id="pid_123"><img src="/123.jpg"></a>
```

So, thanks for @Dimitra for pointing it out. I was surprised with the de-vote but am happy to say i probably deserve it.

Comment: as per updated markup, event.target.getFirst().getProperty("id")

Comment: @Dimitar You should have added your solution as an answer. It did not work though.

Comment: which element do you add the click event to?? this is the 3rd change of markup you do... make your mind up or make a www.jsfiddle.net example! no wonder it got downvoted

Comment: @Dimitar. The event handler nover changed: remove_pid. The code I pasted in update 1 was to to tell @aishwar that event.target.id would work with that code. Update 2 is what I really have. In any case, your solution does not work. But thanks for the down-vote anyway.

Comment: dude you changed your markup 3 times, what do you expect? either apply the logic of your abstraction to your real page or post your real markup / js instead. using `event.target` is possible but you need to consider: in mootools 1.1x the event object is not standardised (check how to use the `new Event(event)` constructor) and it may differ between browsers. try to bind the function to the trigger element instead so `this` points to it within the function. see my reply.

Comment: If you read my comment correctly. I've changed my markup once. Simply because I thought it was inconsequential. But I was wrong. Your assertion that I've changed it three times is incorrect.

Comment: Also your suggestion to post all future js examples to jsfiddle(or similar) is noted.

Comment: RIGHT. `(event.target).getParent('a').getProperty('id');` ? for this to work you need to assign the click event on the IMG and not on the A HREF (`<a href="#" class="remove_pid" id="pid_123"><img src="/123.jpg"></a>`) else, it will be returning an incorrect A. good luck.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/nGrMU/1/ Seems luck is on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I found it:

```
function removePid(event)
{
    //alert('yo what is my element id???');
    $(event.target).getParent('a').getProperty('id');
}
```

This works in FF 3.6

Comment: Correct. I actually have an image inside the link tag instead of the text. Changes made in update 2.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have experience working with mootools. But I would guess you can just do something along these lines, in `removePid`:

```
var element = event.srcElement || event.target
element.id // is the element's id, element is the DOM element itself
```

Answer (score 1):

as per the markup posted in the FINAL update:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/Sr8LC/

```
$$('.remove_pid').addEvents({
    'click': function(e) {
        new Event(e).stop();
        var id = this.getProperty("id");
        alert(id);
        alert(id.replace("pid_", ""));
    }
});
```

to use a named function and keep the event:

```
var removeProduct = function(e) {
    new Event(e).stop();
    var id = this.getProperty("id");
    alert(id);
    alert(id.replace("pid_", ""));
};

$$('a.remove_pid').each(function(el) {
    el.addEvents({
        'click': removeProduct.bind(el)
    });
});
```

within both functions, `this` will refer to the trigger element (the anchor), so you can read it's property, etc. `this.getFirst()` will reference the image (if you want it).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution seems to work in jsfiddle  at the expense of rewriting all of my code. I understand you've put considerable effort into making this cross-browser compatible but my one liner works fine and dandy. Appologies for the initial confusion.